# Half of PHP script not submitting

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a php script to pull from two different tables within the same database. After the data is pulled, it is put into another table that will hold that specific information for later use. Right now, it will submit the userid and username but will not submit the puid variable I have stated.

Here is the script

```
include('data.php');

//Database Connection
$con=@mysql_connect("$ip", "$guser", "$gpass")
            or die(mysql_error());

//Select Database
$dbcon=@mysql_select_db($forums, $con)
            or die(mysql_error());

$search = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select userid, usergroupid, username from $users where username like '%$search%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id = $row['userid'];
    $name = $row['username'];
    $ugid = $row['usergroupid'];
}       

if ($ugid == '21') {

    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO $vip (fuid, username) VALUES ('$id', '$name')";
    $res2 = @mysql_query($sql4, $con) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT $id, field5 FROM $userfield");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
        $puid = $row['field5'];
    }

    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO $vip (puid) VALUES ('$puid')";
    $res = @mysql_query($sql3, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    echo 'Completed';
} else {
    echo 'User is not VIP'; 
}
```

Comment: I would try adding `echo mysql_error();` to all queries, as you generally don't have database tables beginning with a $

Comment: could field5 be returning a NULL value from the DB??

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: You have $tablename set for all your tables... Is this a replace you did to post here? or is $vip defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not doing those queries for all retrieved rows.you should get those queries inside foreach loop otherwise only the last row will be effected!

Comment: All of the tables and databases are defined in the data.php which included